# How do you connect to an external dashDB instance from within Node-Red?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red, dashdb

From my Bluemix dashDB instance I can set up connections to external dashDB instance(s) that are also in Bluemix. However, when creating a Node-Red service, I can only connect to the internal/local dashDB service.

I cannot locate a generic UI to specify the connection information for the external dashDB instance, but I am hoping you can manually set up the external dashDB instance as an input/output node, but how would I do this?

Again, this other instance is on Bluemix, it is just under a different account.

Answer (score 1):

Add the details as a user provided service. The doc for how to do it can be found [here](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/reqnsi.html#user_provide_services). You will have to match the field names provided by a bound service for it to show up in the config dialogue in Node-RED

Comment: thanks. just what I was looking for. however, shocked a node or some other mechanism to establish a connection isn't provided to do this.

Comment: @wzanine - Bluemix welcomes enhancement requests on the IBM Bluemix Ideas site. Feel free to submit an idea here: https://ibm-bluemix.uservoice.com/forums/311383-ibm-bluemix-ideas